# How to increase the performance for estimating `Pi`in Python

Tags: python, performance, pi

I have written the following code in Python, in order to estimate the value of `Pi`. It is called [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) method. Obviously by increasing the number of samples the code becomes slower and I assume that the slowest part of the code is in the sampling part. 
How can I make it faster?

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

a = 1
n = 1000000

s1 = np.random.uniform(0,a,n)
s2 = np.random.uniform(0,a,n)

ii=0
jj=0

for item in range(n):
    if ((s1[item])**2 + (s2[item])**2) < 1:
        ii = ii + 1

print float(ii*4/(n))
```

Do you suggest other (presumably faster) codes?

Comment: Any reason why you would need to calculate this? This has been done a thousand times already (eg. read it from file, or hardcode it).

Comment: The slowness is just inherent in the algorithm - every time you want one more digit of precision, run time increases by 10x. Check out [Pi - modern quest for more digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Modern_quest_for_more_digits) for faster approaches.

Comment: Is there any reason to built two arrays up-front? Why not get two `random.random()` numbers *inside* the loop? However, as @Kevin points out, this algorithm is fundementally `O(n)`, so for large `n` any changes to the precise implementation will make only minimal differences to overall runtime.

Comment: @Caramiriel Don't ask 'why'. Ask 'why not?' Learning how the algorithm works, school, personal experience, and fun are all reasons.

Comment: @Caramiriel I know it is done many times for many years I am although using it just for educational purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bottleneck here is actually your `for` loop. Python `for` loops are relatively slow, so if you need to iterate over a million items, you can gain a lot of speed by avoiding them altogether. In this case, it's quite easy. Instead of this:

```
for item in range(n):
    if ((s1[item])**2 + (s2[item])**2) < 1:
        ii = ii + 1
```

do this:

```
ii = ((s1 ** 2 + s2 ** 2) < 1).sum()
```

This works because `numpy` has built-in support for optimized array operations. The looping occurs in `c` instead of python, so it's much faster. I did a quick test so you can see the difference:

```
>>> def estimate_pi_loop(x, y):
...     total = 0
...     for i in xrange(len(x)):
...         if x[i] ** 2 + y[i] ** 2 < 1:
...             total += 1
...     return total * 4.0 / len(x)
... 
>>> def estimate_pi_numpy(x, y):
...     return ((x ** 2 + y ** 2) < 1).sum()
... 
>>> %timeit estimate_pi_loop(x, y)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.33 s per loop
>>> %timeit estimate_pi_numpy(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
```

Here are a few examples of the kinds of operations that are possible, just so you have a sense of how this works.

Squaring an array:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(5)
>>> a ** 2
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
```

Adding arrays:

```
>>> a + a
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Comparing arrays:

```
>>> a > 2
array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Summing boolean values:

```
>>> (a > 2).sum()
2
```

As you probably realize, there are faster ways to estimate Pi, but I will admit that I've always admired the simplicity and effectiveness of this method.

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned numpy arrays, so you should use those to your advantage.

```
for item in range(n):
    if ((s1[item])**2 + (s2[item])**2) < 1:
        ii = ii + 1
```

becomes

```
s1sqr = s1*s1
s2sqr = s2*s2
s_sum = s1sqr + s2sqr
s_sum_bool = s_sum < 1
ii = s_sum_bool.sum()
print float(ii*4/(n))
```

Where you are squaring the arrays, summing them, checking if the sum is less than 1 and then summing the boolean values (false = 0, true = 1) to get the total number that meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted `senderle`'s answer, but in case you don't want to change your code too much:

[numba](http://numba.pydata.org) is a library designed for this purpose.

Just define your algorithm as a function, and add the `@jit` decorator:

```
 from __future__ import division
 import numpy as np
 from numba import jit

 a = 1
 n = 1000000

 s1 = np.random.uniform(0,a,n)
 s2 = np.random.uniform(0,a,n)

 @jit
 def estimate_pi(s1, s2):
     ii = 0
     for item in range(n):
         if ((s1[item])**2 + (s2[item])**2) < 1:
             ii = ii + 1
     return float(ii*4/(n))

 print estimate_pi(s1, s2)
```

On my laptop, it gains about a 20x speedup for `n = 100000000`, and a 3x speedup for `n = 1000000`.